# loading a dll (can't find function)

Tags: c++, dll

I am trying to dynamically load a dll. The dll is found but when I try to find the function, it won't work.

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
typedef void (__stdcall *f_funci)();

int main(){

HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("C:\\users\\MyWin.dll");

  if (!hGetProcIDDLL) {
    std::cout << "could not load the dynamic library" << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }else{
     std::cout << "Found the dll" << std::endl;
   }

  f_funci funci = (f_funci)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "printSomething");
  if (!funci) {
    std::cout << "could not locate the function" << std::endl;
  }

 return 0;
}
```

and the file for the dll :

**MyWin.h**

```
#define TEST
#ifndef TEST
#define MAKRO __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall 


MAKRO void printSomething();

#endif
```

**MyWin.cpp**

```
#include "MyWin.h"
#include <iostream>

void  printSomething(){
 std::cout<<"Call the function dynamically"<<std::endl;
}
```

Compiled the dll the following way:

```
g++ MyWin.h MyWin.cpp -shared -o MyWin.dll
```

Would appreciate any help

Comment: You need to add `extern "C"` to the declaration in the header file to stop name mangling

Comment: With extern "C" the function will probably be exported as "_printSomething" iirc